# Dynamically allocated object deleted before calling delete?

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to implement a plugin system, but I'm having some problems. In the plugin DLL, I have something like this code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void InitPlugin(PluginManager* pMgr)
{
    pMgr->RegisterPlugin(new MyPluginObject);
}
```

`MyPluginObject` derives from a pure virtual PluginObject class. In `PluginManager::RegisterPlugin()`, the pointer to the plugin object is stored for later use. I can successfully call a function in `MyPluginObject` from within `RegisterPlugin()`, but once `InitPlugin` returns, I get an access violation whenever I try to use the plugin object that was stored in `RegisterPlugin()`. How do I fix this?

Comment: How do you access the plugin object? How do you return the plugin object from the manager? How are the plugin objects stored in the manager?

Comment: @Joachim The plugin objects are accessed like any other pointer to class, e.g. pMyPluginObject->DoSomething(). The pointers to plugin objects are stored in a std::vector<PluginObject*>, and they're returned from the manager from the std::vector (return plugins[n]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course I ask a question here, and figure it out myself 10 minutes later. The problem actually had nothing to do with this, instead I was using my own class to handle the loading of the DLL file. It turns out that class was accidentally deleted earlier than expected, and it unloaded the DLL with it, which invalidated everything from the DLL.